# auto and distinguishing between overloaded methods

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's my example code for some context:

```
//tac.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  auto lines = vector<string>{};
  for(auto line = string{}; getline(cin,line); ){
    lines.emplace_back(line);
  };


  //vector<string>::const_reverse_iterator cit = lines.rbegin();
  //auto cit = lines.rbegin();
  for(
      decltype(lines)::const_reverse_iterator cit = lines.rbegin();
      cit != lines.rend();
      ++cit){
    cout<< *cit << endl;
  };
    return 0;
}
```

In the second for loop, id'd like to have the brevity of `auto` while getting a `const_reverse_iterator` out of `rbegin()`.

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/ ,
`vector`'s `rbegin` has two signatures:

```
 reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept;
 const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept;
```

If I do use

```
  auto cit = lines.rbegin();
```

I get the non-const version of `rbegin` because the compiler then let's me modify the vector (e.g. `*cit = "foo";`) without warning.

How does `auto` picks from the two versions of `rbegin`. Can it be made to pick the second version?

Comment: There's [`crend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rend) in C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [0x499602d2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) points out, there's the `cr?[begin|end]*` family in C++14. In fact, your code basically appears in [Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) (Item 13) with that as the resolution.

For the time being, you can "force" `lines` to be a `const` when you call it, like so:

```
  auto cit = ((const decltype(lines) &)lines).rbegin();
```

While there are other ways, not involving `decltype`, I like this one, as it is invariant to later changes in `lines`'s type.

Answer (score 2):

> How does auto picks from the two versions of `rbegin`. Can it be made to pick the second version?

That is the wrong question. `auto` simply picks the type of `lines.rbegin()`. The question is "How does the compiler pick `rbegin()`?" The answer to *that* is we do overload resolution on the two functions using the object instance as the first argument. So we have:

```
reverse_iterator rbegin(vector<string>& );
const_reverse_iterator rbegin(const vector<string>& );
```

Both overloads are exact matches, but the latter is a reference to a more cv-qualified type (since `lines` is not `const`), so the first will be preferred. That's why you get a `reverse_iterator` for `lines.rbegin()`. `auto` just happily deduces it.

What you want is to force the call itself to give you a `const_reverse_iterator`, which requires you to "pass" a `const` object into `rbegin`. You could do that explicitly:

```
auto cit = const_cast<const vector<string>&>(lines).rbegin();
```

There's even a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4380.html) to make this easier:

```
auto cit = std::as_const(lines).rbegin();
```

But even simpler, there's just a member function that always returns a `const_reverse_iterator`: [`crbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin)

```
auto cit = lines.crbegin();
```

Comment: Nice idea. `template<typename T> const T& as_const(const T& t) { return t; }` seems to do the job. :)